# how to get latest message from firebase database in ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have don't know what the problem please help me. When I get a particular message from firebase database then the value is getting but my app got a crash on one line.So please tell me what I do wrong in my code.below is my function.We also provide the screenshot of the error.

```
 func getLatestMessageFromFirebase(token:String,completionmessage: @escaping (_ message:String) -> Swift.Void)
    {
        print("getModelFromFirebase")
        var message:String=""
        ref.child("chatmessage/devicetoken/").child(token).queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if value?["message"] as? String != ""
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        message = (value?["message"] as? String)! //My app stop on this line
                        completionmessage(message)
                }


            }
        })
        { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

func callAPI()
{
                                let response = (jsonResult.object(forKey: "chatListArr") as? NSArray)!
                                if response.count > 0
                                {
                                    for i in 0..<response.count
                                    {
                                        let dict = response[i] as! NSDictionary
                                        let chatlist = ChatList(dict: dict)
                                        self.arr_list.append(chatlist)
                                    }
                                    for i in 0..<self.arr_list.count
                                    {
                                        let chatlist = self.arr_list[i]
                                        self.getLatestMessageFromFirebase(token: chatlist.token, completionmessage: { (message) in
                                            self.arr_list[i].msg = message
                                        })
                                    }

                                    self.table_view.reloadData()
                                }
}
```

[image]

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should clean your code up a bit, you do a couple of things which would be considered anti patterns

```
 func getLatestMessageFromFirebase(token:String,completionmessage: @escaping (_ message:String) -> Swift.Void)
    {
        ref.child("chatmessage/devicetoken/").child(token).queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as [DataSnapshot] {
              let value = snap.value as? [String: Any] ?? [:] // A good way to unwrap optionals in a single line
              if let message = value["message"] as? String {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionmessage(message)
                  }
              }
           }
        })
        { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

With the above code your app shouldnt crash. And if there is a message AND it is a string (which might have been your problem before) then your callback will fire.

Comment: It does not enter in If condition.

Comment: Then there is no message in the values you are fetching. Do a `print(snapshot.value)` and post what is returns

Comment: It have these values.
["-KxSfTvfhGVxH2Yet8zU": {
    Date = "2017/10/27";
    message = hi;
    sender = web;
    status = 0;
    time = "5:23 PM";
}]

Comment: @GauravGupta did this answer your question? If so, could you mark the question as answered?